# I'm installing a custom WordPress image from Bitnami with Helm. Can't pull image from private repository in Docker Hub

Tags: kubernetes, bitnami, dockerhub

I'm trying to deploy a WordPress instance with custom plugins and theme on Minikube.

First, I've created a custom WordPress Docker Image based on [Bitnami's Image](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress). I've pushed it to Docker Hub and made the repository private.

Now, I'm trying to deploy the Image using Bitnami's [WordPress Helm Chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/wordpress). For this, I:

1. Created a secret `regcred` in the same namespace as the deployment, as described in [Kubernetes Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-secret-by-providing-credentials-on-the-command-line).

   kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1 --docker-username=USERNAME --docker-password=PWORD --docker-email=EMAIL
2. Changed the chart's `values-production.yaml` ([here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/wordpress/values-production.yaml)) to the following:

.

```
## Global Docker image parameters
## Please, note that this will override the image parameters, including dependencies, configured to use the global value
## Current available global Docker image parameters: imageRegistry and imagePullSecrets
##
global:
  imageRegistry: docker.io
  imagePullSecrets:
    - regcred
#   storageClass: myStorageClass

## Bitnami WordPress image version
## ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/wordpress/tags/
##
image:
  registry: docker.io
  repository: MYUSERNAME/PRIVATEIMAGE
  tag: latest
  ## Specify a imagePullPolicy
  ## Defaults to 'Always' if image tag is 'latest', else set to 'IfNotPresent'
  ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#pre-pulling-images
  ##
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  ## Optionally specify an array of imagePullSecrets.
  ## Secrets must be manually created in the namespace.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/
  ##
  pullSecrets:
    - regcred
  ## Set to true if you would like to see extra information on logs
  ##
  debug: true
...
```

I'm thinking that the pod should be able to pull the private repository, but it never can. It's status is stuck at `Waiting: ImagePullBackOff`

Can am I doing wrong? I'm following [this tutorial](https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/deploy-custom-wordpress-production-helm/), btw. Also, I'm running things on my Windows 10 through WSL2 (Ubuntu distro).

Comment: Did you after creating your image publish it at DockerHub. Yop have to have or create an account at DockerHub and login from terminal using  [login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/)  command: sudo docker login. And after successful login, did you rebuild your docker image with your DockerHub username in tag and push it to DockerHub  ? Did you read https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/get-started-kubernetes/ ?

Comment: Yes @Malgorzata, I did everything you said. I think I've solved the issue, as explained in the answer I wrote. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I only had to change the server property in the secret from `https://index.docker.io/v1` to `docker.io`.

I'm now facing another issue, but I think this one is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Gonçalo Figueiredo,

Reproducing this issue, it worked just fine when I used `kubectl create secret docker-registry` and deployed the chart in my GKE cluster in my linux vm.

When I tried using Minikube on my local machine, I did come across a `ImagePullBackOff` error. The problem was that I had recently changed my dockerHub password and the credentials in my host machine were obsolete. Doing a new `docker login` solved the issue.

Not sure if it could be happening something similar on your end. If not, could you please check that your private repo is up and try using another method to create the Secret containing the Docker credentials?

Comment: Thank you for your input @Francisco. I think I've solved the problem, as explained in the answer I wrote. The problem wasn't with the Docker Hub credentials.